# JavaScript Function-Level Scoping

Tags: javascript

In the following example, is a new variable 'y' created for each iteration through the for..in loop?  Or is the variable declaration hoisted to the top of the function, and re-used for each iteration?

```
function example() {
    var x;
    for(x in obj) {
       var y = obj[x];
    } 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hoisted, since the for loop has no effect on scope.

Comment: I figured, just wanted to make sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

y is the same variable being replaced. to make a new one you would use

```
function example() {
    var x;
    var y= new Array;
    for(x in obj) {
       y[x] = obj[x];
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's not right. If you break your loop into two statements: `var y` and `y[x] = obj[x]`, and then read the value of `y` between those two statements, you'll find that `y` still contains the array.  Ie, it is not a new undefined variable.

Comment: y is supposed to still contain the obj array item, but now y can index each item from the obj array. i beleive he was asking if y will hold only the last item in the obj array. which is correct,  by using y[x]  y will contain the same array as obj.

Comment: Then why use the `var` keyword?

Comment: my mistake.  i didnt realize y was defined already when i copied his code
 var y[x] = obj[x];

Answer (score 0):

You can [test this for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/x4wHB/):

```
var obj = {
  name: "Dan",
  surname: "Tao"
};

var x;
for (x in obj) {
  var y = obj[x];
}
alert(y);
```

An alert box will appear with the text `Tao`, indicating that `y` is accessible outside the scope of the `for` loop.